# CSS rendering of <tr> background different in WebKit and Firefox

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table styled like this: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/SGQBF/

On hovering the `tr`s, I would like to show a **bullet** at the *first td* or *tr*.
This is working as expected in Firefox. But in Chrome the bullet is being shown at every `td`.

My questions are

1. Whats wrong with my CSS?
2. How could I correct that?

Comment: tr:hover td:first-child maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's a bug.

Here is a work-around.

```
.datatable tr.row:hover, .datatable tr.altrow:hover {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    color: #000;
}

.datatable tr.row:hover td:first-child, .datatable tr.altrow:hover td:first-child {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    background-image: url(http://quenshsolutions.ie/Images/bullet.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left
}
```

Comment: You should report it, it could be worth $. :)

Comment: reported it. http://www.google.co.in/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=42b9070acd8c596e&hl=en god knows whether i get whip-lashed for my mistake :) and BTW, thanks. i knew this but always tht it was my mistake. did you find any bug with that css?

Answer (score 2):

Changed your rules to this:

```
.datatable tr.row:hover , .datatable tr.altrow:hover{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFFACD;
/* remove background image */
}

.datatable tr.row:hover > td:first-child, .datatable tr.altrow:hover >  td:first-child {
    background-image: url(http://quenshsolutions.ie/Images/bullet.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The css looks fine to me. Why chrome behaves incorrectly I don't know but a quick fix would be to move the bullet from tr to tr first td. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SGQBF/1/)

Answer (score 1):

This would be the edited HTML:

```
<table class="datatable">
    <tr>
        <th class="sortasc-header"><a href="#">Name</a></th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th class="sortdesc-header"><a href="#">Age</a></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="altrow">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="altrow">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="altrow">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="altrow">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="altrow">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
        <td class="first">Naveen</td>
        <td>Consultant</td>
        <td>24 years</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And this would be the edited CSS (Bold is what was edited):

```
.datatable
{
    border: solid 1px #7f7f7f;
    color:#000000;
    width: 100%;
}        
.datatable th
{
    background: url(http://quenshsolutions.ie/Images/sprite.png) repeat-x 0px 0px;
    border-color: #989898 #cbcbcb #989898 #989898;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px medium;
    color: #000;
    padding: 4px 5px 4px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.datatable th a
{ 
    color:#00002B;
    padding-right:18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.datatable th.sortasc-header, .datatable th.sortdesc-header {
    background: url(http://quenshsolutions.ie/Images/sprite.png) repeat-x 0px -100px;
}

.datatable th.sortasc-header a {
    background:url(http://quenshsolutions.ie/Images/asc.gif) right center no-repeat; 
}
.datatable th.sortdesc-header a {
    background:url(http://quenshsolutions.ie/Images/desc.gif) right center no-repeat; 
}
.datatable tr {
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#777;
}
.datatable .row td, .datatable .altrow td 
{
    text-align:left;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-right: solid 1px #cbcbcb;
}
.datatable .row 
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.datatable .altrow 
{
    background-color: #EDF5FF;
}  
.datatable .row td.sortasc-row, .datatable .row td.sortdesc-row
{
    background-color: #EDF5FF;
}
.datatable .altrow td.sortasc-row, .datatable .altrow td.sortdesc-row
{
    background-color: #DBEAFF;
}      
**.datatable tr.row td.first:hover, .datatable tr.altrow td.first:hover{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFFACD;
    background-image:url(http://quenshsolutions.ie/Images/bullet.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.datatable tr.row:hover, .datatable tr.altrow:hover{
    color: #000;
    background-color: #FFFACD;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;    
}**

.datatable .row td.first { padding-left:10px; }
.datatable th.first { padding-left:10px; }
```